# Immediately Invoked functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a clarification in using Immediately Invoked functions (IIFs) in JavaScript.
I have  downloaded a JavaScript file called called test.js as follows and I have got following questions after Googling IIFs:

```
define(function () {

   (function (window) {

    this.test = function() {};
    
   Test.prototype.function1 = function(){
    //Do something
   },
   
   function Delete(){
   //Code to Delete
   }
   window.Delete = Delete;

   })(window);
});
```

I do have the following questions:

1. Is the line,
   `this.test = function() {};` a constructor?
   If so can I have 2 constructors in a single file like for example:

   ```
    this.test = function() {};
    this.test2 = function() {};
   ```

   And also, why would I need a constructor when I know that this is an automatically invoked file where everything gets executed initially itself.
2. Is this a private function?

   ```
    Test.prototype.function1 = function(){
      //Do something
    },
   ```

   Does this not get automatically? Should I need to create an object of the test and then invoke it?
3. Is this a public function?

   ```
    function Delete(){
        //Code to Delete
    }
    window.Delete = Delete;
   ```

   The last line of the above says that . If it is so then whats the difference between first and second function?
4. What is keyword `window` here?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. The answers would be 1) No 2) No 3) No 4) not a keyword

Comment: I don't see any IIFE in your code. And the code appears to be quite crappy. Is this the original code? And where did you download it?

Comment: You're not executing the funtion you need to add `})(window);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that this code will fail with an error, as `Test` is undefined, and you can't set the `prototype` property on `undefined`.

1. In JavaScript, any function can be a constructor. It's up to how you use it. You can add functions and properties to the `.prototype` property of any function, and any objects created from it using `new` will get them from the prototype chain. In your case, `this.test = function(){}` doesn't look like a prototype.
2. There's no such things a "public" or "private" functions in JavaScript, there's only what's exposed via `return` out of the function (or in your case, by using the global `window` object, which is considered bad practice) If the `Test` function is exposed somewhere, then `Test.prototype.function1` is also exposed. All prototype methods are "public".
3. Yes, sort of. Like I said, "public" or "private" isn't a thing in JavaScript. You created a function and placed it on the `window` object, which is global. Essentially, you've made the function global.
4. `window` is the global browser object. Although when used like this `(function(window) { ... })(window)`, the first window is the name of the parameter, (and any instances of `window` inside the function reference to that parameter, and the second one (passed to the function call), is the global `window` object.

Further reading:

- **[The Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)**

Comment: Hi, I have one more clarification: why would the code fail because there is already a test function defined this.test = function() {}; and in the next line Test.prototype has been used.
. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `this.test` and `Test` are two completely different identifiers/objects. They are not equivalent.

Comment: Ok one last clarification, assuming that the code compiles , is this a constuctor ?Test.prototype.function1 = function(){
  //Do something
}   .    If yes , then is it necessary to use prototype object to make it as a constuctor?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-javascript-constructors/